# jquerymobile 1.3.1 & Jquery 2.0 Beta

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've seen a few posts where people have successfully implemented this; my goal being to use the slimmer version of Jquery with Jquery mobile to see if I can get a speed increase.

However I get an error on navigating between pages ( which did work in the previous version of Jquery)

The error is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined - 
jquery.mobile-1.3.1.custom.js:10313

```
 _create: function () {
            var self = this,
                $el = self.element,
                page = $el.closest(":jqmData(role='page')"),
                _getPageTheme = function () {
                    var $theme = $.data(page[0], "mobilePage").options.theme
```

Comment: Are you migrating or starting from scratch? One snag I ran into before was that I didn't update the .css / themes and it completely crippled everything..

Comment: Thanks - I downloaded it all again and same thing.  However I did revert Jquery to jquery-1.9.1.js and it worked; so there must be something different in Beta that breaks the page navigation ( linked in with Themes ).

Comment: Ok further investigation reveals that I have a panel control in the page.  if removed the page starts working.


<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="right"  data-display="overlay">
    xxx      
</div>

Comment: So you think it's a panel bug?

Comment: I have the same problem with panel present, and I'm using jqm1.3.2 and jq2.0.3. If I remove the panel, all is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Propably, it is a compatibility issue:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-0-0-compatibility

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything, page loads were still just stuck on the loading spinner. This only seemed to be an issue when loading page files, rather than multi page files.

Changing back to jQuery 1.9.1 solve this for me